# User Input file directory with spaces?

Tags: c++

I have a simple code that asks a user to input a folder for the program to work within.

```
    char MasterDirectory [50];
cout << "Please enter the directory containing the MP3 files you wish to have organised. " << endl;
cin >> MasterDirectory;

GetFileListing(MasterDirectory, "*.mp3");
```

However, the program doesn't function correctly if the input directory contains a space. 
Sorry for the rookie question, but how can I enclose the variable of "MasterDirectory" in quotation marks for GetFileListing?

Comment: whith std::string instead of a char array it wourld work (besides allocating only 50 characters is qwuite a "short" path)

Comment: 50 was a throwaway number, something I wrote in haste for a test run. Also, apologies for the duplicate topic; can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use

```
cin.getline(MasterDirectory, sizeof(MasterDirectory));
```

Comment: Excellent! That works like a charm. Is sizeof(MasterDirectory) changing the size of the char to the input?

Comment: sizeof in this case computes the size of the buffer as declared

Answer (score 0):

You must use cin.getline(MasterDirectory, 50);

Answer (score 0):

You have to use std::getline to read full line with whitespaces;

> can I enclose the variable of "MasterDirectory" in quotation marks?

Just add them to what you read (I suggest using std::string for flexibility):

```
std::string fileName;
std::cout << "Please enter the directory containing the 
              MP3 files you wish to have organised. " << endl;
std::getline( std::cin, fileName);
GetFileListing( "\"" + fileName + "\"", "*.mp3");
```

http://ideone.com/Lmi149